# Embed MP4 video into forum for Wordpress

Tags: video, mp4

I am currently using the wpforo forum plugin for WordPress. By default the forum for some reason only allows YouTube video. However, I do not use any social media videos or YouTube, just strictly mp4 video.

Here is the code for the function.php file to allow YouTube videos.

Can someone help provide a code so I may just use MP4 videos instead?

Thank you

```
add_filter('wpforo_content_after', 'wpforo_custom_video_embed', 10);
function wpforo_custom_video_embed( $content ){
    $paterns = array();
    $paterns[] = "/<a[^><]+>\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtube.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i";
    $paterns[] = "/<a[^><]+>\s*[a-zA-Z\/\/:\.]*youtu.be\/([a-zA-Z0-9\-_]+)([a-zA-Z0-9\/\*\-\_\?\&\;\%\=\.]*)/i";
    $content = preg_replace($paterns, "<iframe width=\"720\" height=\"405\" src=\"//www.youtube.com/embed/$1\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>", $content);
    return $content;
}
```

I tried to replace the urls with the domain name, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

> *"I tried to replace the urls with the domain name, but it did not work."*

You could also try returning a `<video>` tag instead of an `<iframe>` tag.

**Possible solution:**

**Where**: function input `$content` is an MP4 url (*eg:* https://www.example.com/myvideo.mp4).

```
function wpforo_custom_video_embed( $content )
{
    $output = "<video width=\"640\" height=\"480\" controls> <source src=\"" . $content . "\" type=\"video/mp4\"> </video>";
    
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: Code is untested because I don't use WordPress for many years now. Ask anything about the code if still not working...